# xml string manipulation in velocity

Tags: javascript, velocity

i have a string with XML tags

`<?XML version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<s-d-structure>`
 `<heading>This is title</heading>`
  `<main>`
   `<cad>`
    `<bad>this is formatted html</bad>`
     `<name>some text </name>`
`<title>show</title>`
`</cad>`
`</main>`
`</s-d-structure>`

I want to get the contents between all tags along with the tags without open tag and end tag.

Output should be

Bad: this is formatted html

name: some text

title: Show

how to do this in my velocity template file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Velocity is a templating language, with very little programming capabilities. It is generally used to generate XMLs, not to process them. The VTL itself can't be used for that, but given that you can put any Java object in the context, you could use a tool that knows how to parse an XML string into a DOM, which you could further process. [Velocity Tools](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/) already has an [XmlTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/XmlTool.html), which you could enable and use.

If you can't configure tools in your project, then you could try a simple string processing, although that's very fragile. Don't forget that in Velocity variables are real Java objects, and any public method can be called:

```
#set ($xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <s-d-structure> <heading>This is title</heading>
      <main> <cad>
        <bad>this is formatted html</bad>
        <name>some text </name>
        <title>show</title>
      </cad> </main>
    </s-d-structure>')
## Extract only the main content
#set ($xml = $xml.replaceFirst('(?s).*<cad>(.*)</cad>.*', '$1'))

## There's no #while in Velocity, so we just loop long enough
#foreach ($i in [0..10000])
  ## Extract the first tag
  $xml.replaceFirst('(?s)\s*+<([^>]++)>([^<]*+)</.*+', '$1: $2')
  #set ($xml = $xml.replaceFirst('(?s)\s*+<[^>]++>[^<]*+</[^>]++>(.*+)', '$1'))
  #if ($xml.trim() == '')
    ## Stop the foreach once the string is empty
    #break($foreach)
  #end
#end
```